# Question about surjective continous operator being right invertible

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am reading a proof that a surjective continuous linear operator $T$ on a Hilbert space $H$ is right invertible. I have a question about the proof. The proof (up to the point where I have a question) reads:

> Let $N$ be the null space of $T$ and let $T_{0}$ be the restriction of $T$ to $N^{\perp}$. Since $H = N \oplus N^{\perp}$, it is clear that $T_{0}: N^{\perp} \rightarrow H$ is a continuous vector space isomorphism...

Why is it that $T_{0}$ is a bijection? Suppose I want to try to show that $T_{0}$ is surjective. Take an $h \in H$. Then $h = n_{1} + n_{2}$ where $n_{1} \in N$, $n_{2} \in N^{\perp}$. Then $T(n_{1}) + T_{0}(n_{2}) = h$, but this doesn't show surjection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T_0$ is surjective cause $T$ is, and injective cause you killed the kernel of T!

Let $h \in H$, pick any $x \in H$ such that $Tx=h$ (exists by surjectivity).
Write $x=x_1 + x_2 \in N \oplus N^\perp$. Then $Tx_1=0$, so $Tx_2=T_0x_2=h$, and you're done for surjectivity.

Finally, if $T_0x=0$, for any $x \in N^\perp$, then $Tx=0$, so $x \in N$, and $x \in N \cap N^\perp=\lbrace 0 \rbrace =\ker T_0$, and you have the bijectivity!

Comment: I guessed this was the why, however, if I give you an $h \in H$, which $x$ is such that $T_{0}x = h$. Also I'm not sure what you mean by killed the kernel of $T$?